# Python: Two script working with same file , one updating it another deleting the data when processed

Tags: python, synchronization

Firstly I am new to Python.
Now my question goes like this:

I have a call back script running in remote machine
which sends some data and run a script in local machine
which process that data and write to a file. Now another
script of mine locally needs to process the file data
one by one and delete them from the file if done.
The problem is the file may be updating continuoulsy.
How do i schyncronize the work so that it doesnt mess up
my file.
Also please suggest me if the same work can be done in some
better way.

Comment: Please let me know if the problem is not clear.

Comment: Maybe you need to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419888/reading-from-a-frequently-updated-file

Comment: @user1501994 Which operating system?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to look into named pipes or sockets which seem to be more suited for your purpose than a file. If it's really just between those two applications and you have control on the source code of both.

For example, on unix, you could create a pipe like (see [os.mkfifo](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.mkfifo)):

```
import os
os.mkfifo("/some/unique/path")
```

And then access it like a file:

```
dest = open("/some/unique/path", "w")  # on the sending side
src = open("/some/unique/path", "r")   # on the reading side
```

The data will be queued between your processes. It's a [First In First Out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO) really, but it behaves like a file (mostly).

If you cannot go for named pipes like this, I'd suggest to use IP sockets over localhost from the [`socket`](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html) module, preferably DGRAM sockets, as you do not need to do some connection handling there. You seem to know how to do networking already.

Comment: But as i mentioned , the first script will keep appending some data to the file.The second script may be will read line by line and do some work and if success it should remove that data(each line) from that file. Will pipe help in this scenario. As  far as i know pipe is to use for reading from one and writing from another end.

Comment: Ah, now I see the point. You did not mention that deleting the line occurs only on success. Hm. In that case you could try to the following. Use the fifo for IPC and write out the lines which did _not_ work out successfully to a new file. The new file will have the same contents as the intermediate file had in your scenario, but it will be easier to manage.

Comment: One more question here. At some point of time the intermediate file(pipe) will become huge. How do i trim that to make it less as older data will not be needed any more .

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the situation correctly. The fifo is a linear structure and there is a limit in size. This implies that if the queue is full, the writing process will block while trying to write. If you need realtime transmission and the possibility to discard old (unprocessed) data, you possibly need a different solution, maybe based on Datagram sockets and threading.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a database whose transactions allow for concurrent processing.

Comment: Thanks for your sugesstion. But the amount of data which the script will handle is very less.