# Read multiple log file in realtime

Tags: python, multithreading, file-io

I have to read data from log files present in realtime. I used the code mentioned in [Reading multiple files in real time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38597535/reading-multiple-files-in-real-time?answertab=active#tab-top) however I am able to read only the first file i.e system.log. How to read all the files iteratively i.e first system.log and then wifi.log and repeat the same process again.

```
import time
import glob
import threading

def follow(thefile):
   thefile.seek(0,2)
    while True:
        line = thefile.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        yield line


 lock = threading.Lock()

 def printFile(logfile):
    loglines = follow(logfile)
    for line in loglines:
        lock.acquire()
        print (line)
        lock.release()



  if __name__ == '__main__':
      files=['system.log','wifi.log']
      for log in files:
          logfile = open(log, "r")
          t = threading.Thread(target = printFile,args = (logfile,))
          t.start()
```

Comment: If you are on unix you can use system calls to achieve this very easily. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523044/how-can-i-tail-a-log-file-in-python

Comment: @mama I have to use this code for linux systems

Comment: linux is unix: so you can use the link from my first comment.

Comment: I am able to do that for single file. I have to do the same for multiple files.

Comment: As you see on the question one of the methods are `Non-Blocking` so you can use it to follow multiple files concurrently. I can make an example for you in a moment.

Comment: @mama Can you share the code for the same.

Comment: After looking a bit on the answers on the link i showed you I saw an answer lower down which seemed much better. I optimized it a bit for your usecase.,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `asyncio` library to create a concurrent function to follow the file's tail and then print it.

```py
import asyncio

async def follow(thefile):
    thefile.seek(0,2)
    while True:
        line = thefile.readline()
        if not line:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        yield line.strip()

async def main(path):
    async for x in follow(open(path)):
        print(x)

for path in ['hej', 'med', 'dig']:
    asyncio.ensure_future(main(path))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_forever()
```

You could also skip the main function and the yield in the follow function, and just print the output directly in the follow function instead of passing it.

Comment: Still it is reading for the first file, not for all.

Comment: Yes I made a mistake. The `yield from` is apparently blocking so we don't get the rest of the generators.