# reading last line in logfile with python

Tags: python, file, tail

When trying to monitor a logfile for new lines with python I stumbled upon an issue.

What I try to do:

```
while True:
    file = open("log.txt", "r")
    file.seek(0,2)
    where = file.tell()
    line = file.readline()

    if not line:
        time.sleep(1)
        file.seek(where)
    else:
        *do stuff with line*
```

The line returned is always empty. I see why this is:

```
file.seek(0,2)
```

will always move the cursor to the end of the file and therefore there is no line after the cursor. But to watch the logfile for only new lines I will need to do this.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to approach something like this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136168/get-last-n-lines-of-a-file-with-python-similar-to-tail does this look useable?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419888/reading-from-a-frequently-updated-file