# Continuously read the last line of log file in python

Tags: python, file

I have a file in which new lines are continuously written.

In python, I would like to continuously read the last line of this file, so that I can process the line.

I know there is the `readlines()` function but this is "static". If new lines are added after I called `readlines()` these new lines will not be read.

How can I do this in python ?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading from a frequently updated file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419888/reading-from-a-frequently-updated-file)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a "state machine". That is just a fancy way of saying, you want to keep track of where in the file you are, so you amy `seek()` to that position, `read()` to the end of file, and read and advance the current position everytime you encounter a newline.

You could use something like this, which could also be used like an iterator:

```py
import time


class LogFollower:
    def __init__(self, fp):
        self.position = 0
        self.fp = fp

    def seek(self):
        self.fp.seek(self.position)

    def has(self):
        self.seek()
        return '\n' in self.fp.read()

    def __iter__(self):
        while self.has():
            self.seek()
            line = self.fp.read().split('\n')[0]
            yield line

            # advance position - this is the 'state machine' part!
            self.position += len(line) + 1

follow = LogFollower(open("my_file.txt"))

# assume the file already has 2 lines

for line in follow:
    print(line)

#>foo
#>bar

time.sleep(5)

# now suppose a line 'baz' is added to the bottom
# somewhere during those 10 secs, then you decide
# to iterate again.

for line in follow:
    print(line)

#>baz
```

You can also continuously check it for new lines by iterating again, like shown in the hypothetical example above, when `baz` is appended.

Please note that, this way, every line must **end** with a linefeed (`\n`). This makes things simpler, and I suppose might be why it is the usual convention anyway.

This example takes a slightly more hands-on approach than just a simple `readline` loop like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5420116/5129091). I reckon it takes a bit more line-count this way. However, I believe it is cleaner for illustrative purposes; I suppose it does a good enough job at explaining the basics of the task with simple object-oriented programming.

P.S. I probably call `seek` a couple more times than I really need to. I could, for instance, not call it in the `has()` function, after each run of the `for` loop in `__next__`. I decided to keep it this way, though, for illustrative clarity. :)

P.P.S. I know it's not really what a state machine is. I mean in a very broad sense. Actual finite state machines are an entirely different concept. All this does is increment a counter every time it encounters a new line. I hope it's not too misleading, and that the actual point I was trying to make still remains clear – *keeping track*.