# Reading a dynamically updated log file via readline

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, python-3.6, readline

I'm trying to read a log file, written line by line, via readline.
I'm surprised to observe the following behaviour (code executed in the interpreter, but same happens when variations are executed from a file):

```
f = open('myfile.log')
line = readline()
while line:
  print(line)
  line = f.readline()
# --> This displays all lines the file contains so far, as expected
    
# At this point, I open the log file with a text editor (Vim),
# add a line, save and close the editor.

line = f.readline()
print(line)
# --> I'm expecting to see the new line, but this does not print anything!
```

Is this behaviour standard? Am I missing something?

Note: I know there are better way to deal with an updated file for instance with generators as pointed here: [Reading from a frequently updated file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419888/reading-from-a-frequently-updated-file). I'm just interested in understanding the issue with this precise use case.

Comment: can you share the file contents also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific use case, the explanation is that Vim uses a write-to-temp strategy. This means that all writing operations are performed on a temporary file.

On the contrary, your scripts reads from the original file, so it does not see any change on it.

---

To further test, instead of Vim, you can try to directly write on the file using:

```
echo "Hello World" >> myfile.log
```

You should see the new line from python.

Answer (score 0):

for following your file, you can use this code:

```
f = open('myfile.log')

while True:
    line = readline()
    if not line:
        print(line)
```